# Exception in thread java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized

Tags: java, multithreading, encryption, cryptography, illegalstateexception

At runtime, getting java.lang.IllegalStateException with Cipher not initialized message while decypting ciphertext
my code is as below:

```
public String decrypt(String cipherText) throws SecurityException {
        String clearText = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/OFB/NoPadding");
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(cipherText.getBytes());
            byte[] iv = ArrayUtils.subarray(cipherTextBytes, 0, INIT_VECTOR_LENGTH);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
            byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher
                    .doFinal(ArrayUtils.subarray(cipherTextBytes, INIT_VECTOR_LENGTH, cipherTextBytes.length));
            clearText = new String(decryptedBytes, CHARACTER_ENCODING).trim();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | UnsupportedEncodingException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
        return clearText;
    }
```

Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized
at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCipherState(Cipher.java:1749)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2156)

and this is intermittent issue, after some time it decrypts ciphetext and works as expected.

Answer (score 9):

`Cipher` instances are a stateful and inherently not thread safe. You should not share them between threads at all. And there is no need either, as they are relatively lightweight objects; making them thread safe would probably slow down the application more than simply recreating the object instance. *It is much better to put the key into a field and share that* if you need key reuse. *Then simply call `getInstance("AES/OFB/NoPadding")` and assign the `Cipher` instance to a local variable*.

Side note: the code seems to contain *two* issues: `cipher` is a field (first issue), but as it is initialized each time within `decrypt` (second issue). That means that the the `init` call may actually replace the object instance for `CipherSpi` or `Security.Service` (i.e. the implementation of the cipher) from within another thread, leading to the error you are getting now.

As always with multi-threading, it may well be that you don't get an error in specific circumstances: the program is however erroneous and may crash later on.